# Cordova-supported Node.js version

Tags: cordova

It seems that Cordova doesn't support Node.js v5.0, `cordova build` does nothing now. I believe the Node version I've used before was 0.12.x. Can I find the cordova-node compatibility table somewhere?

Comment: update to cordova 5.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is an official compatibility table, but the most recent [Cordova release](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/11/04/tools-release.html) claims to support Node 4 and 5. Have you tried updating to this version?

Comment: Thanks, the latest release fixed the issue.